# Use ArrayList to store Strings

Tags: java, database, generics, arraylist, containers

I have to create a Media Library for a tasksheet, which stores Peoples Information (Normal People, Artists, Bands) and Media(Audio [audio length - type String] Video[Size - type String])

I started creating a MediaContainer Class, which (through ArrayList) allows me to store information of type String.
So I thought I would simply create two classes (MediaContainer which is supposed to hold the data, and Information Class which has all the methods to fill it - I'm a beginner so extra question: am I doing it right?)

**The Help i really need is assurance or advice from more experienced users in a form of feedback (so i know i'm heading the right way).**
This is how far I am -

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MediaContainer {

    ArrayList<String> Media = new ArrayList<String>();

    public MediaContainer(String addmedia) {
        Media.add(addmedia);
        System.out.println("this is the list :"+Media);
    }
}
```

How should I proceed?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume Artists != Normal People. ;)

Comment: Artists > Normal People ?

Comment: Looks fine. You can be a little more confident I think.

Comment: Write `private List<String> media = new ArrayList<>();` -- respect Java naming conventions, program to interfaces, use proper encapsulation. Also, I don't find your constructor meaningful: it accepts only one list element.

Answer (score 2):

I would write a simple unit test to show you can add the information you need and retrieve it.

I would also try to;

- follow Java Coding Conventions e.g. camelCase variables.
- make fields `final` and `private` where possible.
- use interface instead of concrete types for collections where possible e.g. `List`
- I assume you will need a custom class `Media` to record the information associated with media. i.e. one String will not be enough.

Comment: And I would also not separate `Artists` from `Normal People`.  ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey.. Can you help me out in this question: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14252520/is-there-any-available-api-to-represent-various-units-of-item-like-kg-litre-me if you haven't already seen it. I'm afraid that question is now burried deep, and I haven't got any convincing answer :(